# jQuery + ajax livesearch

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, livesearch

I am doing a mysql database search and retrieving some results via ajax livesearch using the example on w3schools and i want to manipulate those results (drag and drop them) but im having a problem because the script loads before you enter the search and get the results so it does absolutely nothing no the search results. Any thoughts on this matter ?

Comment: Which example on w3schools? are you using the jqueryui autocomplete plugin (jqueryui.com)? and are YOU manipulating the results (not drag and drop) or is the user? Is this drag and drop or sortable? These calls and initializations shouldbe done on document ready not script load, that might a good place to start. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: im using this live search http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp and i'm trying to drag and drop the results like here http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/shopping-cart-php-jquery/demo.php . I know for sure that the search is working properly i replaced it with the live search and it works just fine but when using the livesearch (and watching it with firebug/chrome console) i notice that the divs and classes are not affected by the script at all, are you saying that the fact that the results are displayed after the script has loaded has nothing to do with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - thanks for the clarification.

The elements you want to drag are being created after the drag/drop initialization. You need make them draggable:

for example, add 'dragMe' as a class to the items. Once the list is populated from the server, then make those items dragable:

```
$('.dragMe').draggable();
```

I would *really* look into jQuery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) functions and their [autocomplete](http://www.jqueryui.com)

To clarify and for jquery (against your cited example):

```
function showUser(str)
{
   $.get( 'getuser.php', { q: str },
       function(data) {
          $('#txtHint').html( data ); // add the returned content to #txtHint
          $('#txtHint').find('.dragItem').draggable(); //make the new items draggable
       }, 'html' );
}
```

In your php, change your display so it is blocks that can be dragged.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<div class="dragItem">"; // see how we're adding the 'dragItem' class? 
  echo "Firstname " . $row['FirstName'];
  echo "</div>";
  }
```

past that, you'll really want to do some more research to get a better idea of whats going on.

Comment: could you be a bit more precise please, how to i make them draggable after they are created ?

Comment: thank you ! i can now drag the items, if its not too much .. the items that i now drag have the draggable function and i understand how you added it but they don't act like the normal ones(that load with the page) i cannot drop them on the droppable div and they don't have the same properties

        containment: 'document',
 opacity: 0.6,
 revert: 'invalid',
 helper: 'clone',
 zIndex: 100

what else do i need to do to make them drop properly into the div ?